Make vscode respect camel case when move cursor by word
By default, when move cursor by word, via ctrl + left or right, it doesn't respect camel case.
Both Eclipse / Idea can respect camel case when use the shortcut.
Is there anyway to make vscode respect the camel case?
BTW, there is a similar question about visual studio (here), but not about vscode.

What do you mean by that?  What is it doing that you don't want it to do?

@TimRoberts I mean move cursor to jump by words, I've updated the question a bit.

(I figured out the solution, so I want to create both the question & answer, to share with others, since there is no existing question to add an answer to).
In vscode:

cursorWord shortcuts, means jump without respect to camel case.
By default, ctrl + left/right is assigned to these shortcuts.
cursorWordPart shortcuts, means jump with respect to camel case.
By default, they have no shortcuts assigned.

Thus the solution is:

First, add shortcut that respect camel case:

cursorWordPartLeft set to: ctrl + left
cursorWordPartRight set to: ctrl + right
cursorWordPartLeftSelect set to: ctrl + shift + left
cursorWordPartRightSelect set to: ctrl + shift + right


Then, remove shortcut that don't respect camel case:

cursorWordLeft
cursorWordRight
cursorWordLeftSelect
cursorWordRightSelect



Tips:

Shortcuts with Select means jump & select.
use ctrl + k, ctrl +s to open the shortcut config page.

